# Setting up cellspace properly for table in latex

Tags: latex

I want to make a table with 20 images which looks like that:

[image]

I've also set up `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` but images are still touching the bottom `\hline` in every cell. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Maybe `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}` works within a group including `longtable`.